# Best way to create ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uistoryboardsegue

I have an app with a `TableView`. `TableViewCell` contains a `UILabel`, which can contain URLs. I want these URL to open in a `WebView`.

Right now I'm opening Safari when user taps a link ( I'm using `KILabel`). 
What I want to do is to open these links in my app, by creating a new `ViewController` that contains `UIWebView`.

I'm wondering what is the best way to achieve it? 
Is it better to use storyboards or not? Do I need to create storyboard programmatically or from InterfaceBuilder?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this problem. Here is one solution using NSUS

1. create a new view controller and embed a webview.
2. create a view controller class and link the webview to that view controller class
3. in the table view controller class, when a user taps on a url change create an IBAction that saves that URL as a NSUuserDefault like this

`let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("http://www.ThisIsTheLinkThatWasClicked", forKey: "currentActiveURLKey")`

4.now you can access thus URL from any view **AND** when the app is closed and reopened, the data is saved

5. you can retrieve it like this

`let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let url = defaults.stringForKey("currentActiveURLKey")
{
    println(url)
}`